# Java package politics

Tags: java, package

I always doubt when creating packages, I want to take advantage of the package limited access but at the same time I want to have similar classes divided into packages.
The problem comes when you understand that packages are not hierarchical in Java:

> At first, packages appear to be
>   hierarchical, but they are not.
>   [source](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

Imagine I have an API defined with its classes at foo.bar, only the classes the API client needs are set public. Then I have another package with some internal objects I need in the API defined at foo.bar.pojos, this classes need to be public so they can be accessed by foo.bar but this means the API client could also access them if the package foo.bar.pojos is imported.

What is the common package politic that should be followed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen two ways of doing.

The first one consists in separating the public API and internal classes into two different artefacts (jars). The documentation is separated as well, and it's thus easy for the end user to make the distinction between what is internal and what is not. But it sometimes make things more complex to have two jars, two source trees, etc.

The second one consists in delivering a single jar, but have a good documentation allowing to know what's internal and what's not. The textual documentation can explain how to use the API (and thus avoids talking about the internals). And the javadoc can specify that a class is for internal use and is thus subject to changes.

Comment: two jars seems unwieldy, but multiple source trees that eventually get compiled together (one with the public classes, one or more for the various package-private classes, divided by their subject) might be a good (and totally doable) idea. +1

Comment: The second one is what is generally done. Unfortunately, Eclipse does not read the textual documentation about internal classes, and fills up your class-search auto-complete options with everything "public".

Comment: That's why Eclipse has Type filters (under preferences/Java/Appearance)

Comment: I understand Java is quite limited on this aspect, packaging two jars feels just too much.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Java packages don't give you enough control over your dependencies.  The classic way to deal with this is to put external APIs in one package and internal implementation classes in another, and rely on people's good sense to avoid creating dependencies on the latter.

With Maven and OSGI, you have an additional mechanism for managing dependencies between modules / bundles of packages.  In the case of OSGI, you can explicitly declare some packages as not exported, and an OSGI aware development environment will prevent people creating harmful dependencies.  Maven's module support is weaker, but at least it controls dependency cycles.

Finally, you could use custom PMD rules to enforce your project's modularization conventions ... in the same way that there are rules to discourage dependencies on Java's "com.sun.*" package tree.

Answer (score 1):

It is a mess.

Using only what Java itself offers, you have to put everything in the same package. You end up with a single (or a few) packages with lots of classes, and no good way to group them for yourself (but at least that problem does not leak outside). Most people don't do that, though, and as a result, your (as a developer on top of these libraries) public classpath is littered with stuff you should never need to see.

You might like OSGi, which has (and enforces) the concept of bundle-private packages. Those are not exported to the outside world.